# Explain rewriting of expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Can someone explain why $$\bigg(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10}\bigg)e^{(-1+2i)t}$$ is equal to writing $$\bigg(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10}\bigg)\bigg(e^{-t}\cos 2t+i e^{-t} \cdot \sin 2t \bigg)$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $e^{2it} = \cos 2t + i\sin 2t$ by Euler's formula.

Answer (score 1):

In Euler's way of expressing a complex number $z$,

$$z=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

So, in your case,

$$(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10})(e^{(-1+2i)t})=(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10})(e^{-t}e^{i2t})=\bigg(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10}\bigg)\bigg(e^{-t}\cos 2t+i e^{-t}  \sin 2t \bigg)$$

Comment: Your last line is incorrect, as you did a typo when copying OP's original expression : $(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10})(e^{(-t+2i)t})$ should be $(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10})(e^{(-1+2i)t})$. I can't edit your answer so I'll leave it here :)